# how to append application hosted server "hosts" file with below entry

Tags: python, linux, hosting

Suppose I have:

```
14.240.231.138 -ip address
vrrrp.air.lk-host name

https://vrrrp.air.lk:8442/VerReh/services/rgeVerService/wsdl/rgeVerService.wsdl
```

Whenever i run this link i got an error:

```
server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

Can anyone please let me know how to host ip address and hostname so that the links shows xml file

Comment: please let me know i am struggling with this

Comment: any approach will be apreciable

Comment: Are you sure that the DNS is mapping vrrrp.air.lk ? Which IP does it map to? ( Try to do a PING VRRRP.AIR.LK ) Is this IP accessible from the computer you are trying to access it from?

Comment: i tried to do a ping it is telling name or service not known

Comment: Then I think the hostname doesn't exists in the DNS.

Comment: Maybe you can access it as 14.240.231.138:8442/VerReh/services/rgeVerService/wsdl/rgeVerService.wsdl

Comment: no  it is not not working

Comment: before using the link he asked me to do this Make sure to append application hosted server "hosts" file with below entry

Comment: any other way to it

Answer (score 0):

You question is how to adjust the hosts file?

I think this covers what you need:

https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_use_the_hosts_file/

Comment: i followed this link but how to do for a https link

Comment: I don't think there is a difference. Thats just defining the protocol you are using when connecting. This is merely a matter of matching a hostname with a specific IP address.

Comment: is it problem with a link

Comment: I doubt that. Why don't you try to make the necessary addition to the hosts file, and try it out? If it doesn't work, simply roll back your change.